# How to update firmware on a PCoIP Zero Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace

I have purchased the following model zero-client: 10ZIG V1206-P ZERO CLIENT

The client has firmware version 5.0.2 but I need to update the firmware to 6+ to connect it to an amazon workspace.

I have zero knowledge in this field. I've been connecting to the workspace via the windows client for a bit and wanted to use a dedicated device, but I just don't know how to set it up. Can anyone point me at where to begin? I assume upgrading to 6+ will allow me to connect to AWS directly without a need for a manager (which I don't have the knowledge to set up).

Comment: Also, I _think_ this is the right site to post this, but if not could someone point me in the right direction? I'm usually skulking about in stackoverflow, but definitely not the place for a hardware question.

Comment: It should be as simple as logging into the configuration page of the device.  However, I have never used a zero client, without connecting it directly to a PCoIP server.  What does the manual, with regards to the methods you can use to upgrade the firmware, say for the device?

Comment: There are a lot of options for connections, power, and display in the configuration menu, but nothing along the lines of an update.

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://www.10zig.com/resources/support_faq/firmware-update

Comment: @BryantJackson - I have dozens of zero clients on my network, but they are an entirely different brand, but in my case, there is a method to upload the firmware to the device.  Now this configuration page might actually be a byproduct of the manager server it's connected to, but it appears you need to install something on your desktop that is connected to the same network as the zero client in order to upgrade the firmware on the device.

Comment: Anyways they put information about the firmware, [beyond an email information wall](https://www.10zig.com/resources/support_faq), which makes it impossible for me to get installation instructions.  So email support@10zig.com and have them provide the instructions.

Comment: [Anyways](https://www.10zig.com/application/files/7314/9452/5787/Tera2_PCoIP_Zero_Client_Firmware_4.x_and_Remote_Workstation_Card_Firmware_4.9_Administrator_Guide.pdf) you need a management console to update the firmware of your device.  The tool I found was for their thin clients.  "The PCoIP Management Console (MC) lets you centrally manage the devices in your
PCoIP deployment. It is packaged as a VMware® virtual machine (VM), running on
VMware Player."  - Only you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

For historical purposes, my solution:

Was actually rather easy. I just needed to connect to the zero-client machine via a browser on the same network. This may be documented somewhere but I could not find it.

Comment: This is what I suggested from the start, you indicated, you could not find any method to upload a firmware to the device.  Can you go into more detail?  I spent over 2 hours researching this problem to only conclude you needed the free PCoIP management console VM to update the firmware

Comment: To clarify, there was little documentation on updating a single device. Most documentation covered more elaborate setups managed by some sort of management software or server. Accessing the zero-client via browser was a shot in the dark. Their support team confirmed this was the appropriate method over the weekend.